# RPi Keyboard Issues

Tags: keyboard

I'm having problems with my newly acquired RPi.  I've tried multiple power units, settling for the USB Hub in my Dell monitor (a 1911b).  eLinux.org states Dell monitors are fine for powering the device - so no issues there.  The RPi boots to a login prompt for both Raspbian and Arch Linux ARM.

When it comes to keyboards, however, I'm at a loss as to why none respond.  I've tried a Logitech K400 (what I'd prefer to use), Logitech K120 and a Xenta SK-020EL.  None of these work.

I also noticed that I seem not to get any IP address via ethernet either.  I guess I'll have to see if that can be sorted with dhclient after getting a working keyboard.

I would appreciate if anyone could advise me as to why I might be facing these keyboard issues, and how I might resolve it.

Kind Regards

Comment: Are all of these wireless keyboards? I've had zero problems with a cheap wired keyboard, but there seems to be a rash of questions about getting wireless ones to work.

Comment: Only the K400 is wireless, the K120 and SK-020EL are both wired.  I've tried connecting them directly to the RPi, and also via a USB hub, connected to the RPi.  Keystrokes don't register either way.

Comment: Not really my area of expertise. For the wireless one, I'd be suspicious of a driver problem for the adapter.  But for a wired keyboard, all that comes to mind is that it might need more power than the Pi can provide.  But even that goes away if you're using a powered hub.

Comment: I've got an old ThinkPad keyboard with an internal USB 1.1 hub that doesn't work when plugged directly (well, through an OTG adapter) into my Zero W, but does work when plugged into a USB 2.0 hub which is in turn plugged into the Zero. (It works fine on a Debian 8 laptop.) It seems that the USB code and/or controller still has quirks. Make sure you've downloaded the latest software, and let us know exactly what model of Pi and software you're using.